# Chat Server - client/server chat Java homework

Tags: java

My chat room program. I have 2 packages, 1 for Client & other for Server. Run Server program, fill the PortField and click button Start Server, window program is stuck, i cant do anything on it, but Server still work, Clients still connect and chat.

```
private void btnOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    int port = Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText());
    go(port);
}                                       
private void go(int port){
    try {
        listUser = new Hashtable<String, ClientConnect>();
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        txaStatus.append("Server is started\n");
        txaStatus.append("IP Server : "+InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()+"\n");
        txaStatus.append("Port : " + port + "\n");
        while(true){
            client = server.accept();
            new ClientConnect(this,client);//class ClientConnect for DataOutPut & DataInput Client <=> Server
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        txaStatus.append("Server cannot start\n");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Port busy","warning",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mouny Whats the problem? Glad you are doing the homework :)

Comment: If you are told to go to country `X` and country `Y` at the same time, how will you do that? ;)

Comment: You should also be aware of the Event Dispatch Thread (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run your server in the GUI Thread, this will prevent the program from accepting any other input.  You need to move the `go()` method into a separate thread.

Comment: If you attempt to run the server in the GUI thread, then that thread can't get back to updating the GUI until you exit the loop that waits for and accepts client network messages.  You need two threads, so you can effectively do two things more-or-less at once, handle the clients, and keep the GUI up-to-date.

Comment: Thank all very much. I solved it with 2 threads. Just beginner with Java :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's safe to assume that you've already been introduced to multi-threading, given the nature of this assignment.   This sounds like a good time to try some of that.